# sparkR reading csv ERROR return status==0 not TRUE

Tags: r, csv, apache-spark, sparkr

I started my spark shell using

```
>>./bin/sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0
```

Now I am trying to read a csv in sparkR shell

```
d <- read.df(sqlContext,
    "data/mllib/sample_tree_data.csv","com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
```

But every time I am getting an error

> Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE

logs while starting sparkR shell are as below:

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) -- "Warm Puppy"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Launching java with spark-submit command /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit   "--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0" "sparkr-shell" /tmp/RtmpXZM96Y/backend_porte2670057297 
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/ravimanik/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/ravimanik/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/alti-spark-1.4.1.hadoop24.hive13/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.4.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10;1.2.0 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.1 in central
    found com.univocity#univocity-parsers;1.5.1 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 297ms :: artifacts dl 30ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10;1.2.0 from central in [default]
    com.univocity#univocity-parsers;1.5.1 from central in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.1 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   3   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   3   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 3 already retrieved (0kB/21ms)

 Welcome to SparkR!
 Spark context is available as sc, SQL context is available as sqlContext
```

Comment: Wrong path -  `"data/mllib/sample_tree_data.csv"`?

Comment: @zero323 Sorry that was a typo...I am still getting the same error

Comment: If so please provide a full  traceback.

Comment: @zero323 I have added the logs

Comment: It is a step in the right direction but not exactly what we need here. Between the method call and  `Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE` there should a large block of text. Please copy and paste that.

Comment: I guess you should update R

Comment: @grubjesic Thanks alot. It Worked after updating R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met exactly the same problem. It works after I restart R-session.